# Next JS and uploading images to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, file-upload, google-cloud-storage, next.js

I am trying to use Next JS and ultimately Vercel to handle image uploads with Google Cloud Storage and I'm getting mixed results.

I have a basic upload taken from some docs that looks like this:

```
function NewBet(props) {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
     src: '',
  })

  const { src } = state

  const registerUser = async (event) => {

    event.preventDefault()

    //Upload image to Google
    const file = src
    const filename = encodeURIComponent(file.name)

    console.log('filename: ', filename)
    const resImg = await fetch(`/api/upload?file=${filename}`)
    const url = await resImg.json()
    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('file', filename)

    const upload = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
    })

    if (upload.ok) {
      console.log('Uploaded successfully!')
    } else {
      console.error('Upload failed.')
    }
  }

 const onSelectFile = (e) => {
   if (e.target.files && e.target.files.length > 0) {
     setState({ ...state, src: e.target.files[0] })
   }
 }
 .....
 <form onSubmit={registerUser} className="myForm">
     <OCRCompoonent onOCRReturned={handleOCR} onSelectFile={onSelectFile} />
 .....
 </form>
```

And my upload looks like this:

```
import { Storage } from '@google-cloud/storage'

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const storage = new Storage({
    projectId: process.env.PROJECT_ID,
    credentials: {
      client_email: process.env.CLIENT_EMAIL,
      private_key: process.env.PRIVATE_KEY,
    },
  })

  const bucket = storage.bucket(process.env.BUCKET_NAME)
  const file = bucket.file(req.query.file)
  const options = {
    expires: Date.now() + 1 * 60 * 1000, //  1 minute,
    fields: { 'x-goog-meta-test': 'data' },
  }

  const [response] = await file.generateSignedPostPolicyV4(options)
  res.status(200).json(response)
}
```

And this is basically my env variables

So 1) I'm getting Image uploaded successfully in the console log but nothing seems to be added to my Cloud Bucket, and number 2...
When deployed to Vercel I get...

```
[clubid]-f98a4d840994ca2053e3.js:1 POST https://xxxxxx.xxxxx.app/club/[object%20Object] net::ERR_ABORTED 500
(anonymous) @ [clubid]-f98a4d840994ca2053e3.js:1
...more error code....

react_devtools_backend.js:2557 Upload failed.
```

Am i doing anything obviously wrong? Thanks

[image]